How to make USB devices work better on an aging desktop?
I have a 7 year old desktop computer (Dell XPS, i7-7700, 16Gb, Windows 10) which is still working very well and my preferred work computer.
However when I plugged a new Logitech USB webcam into it, the picture stuttered and froze to the point that it was not usable. When I plugged a new set of USB speakers into it, the sound also broke up repeatedly and in the end they were not usable either.
This makes me think there may be a problem with USB devices in general on this computer - how can I make these work better? Would it perhaps be useful to replace the USB port card?

Without understanding the specifications of the device its difficult to make recommendations but an USB PCIe card is unlikely to make any difference

Some application use more resources for higher-resolution cameras. For example, Zoom Workplace has a setting for video to switch between "HD" and lower resolution. On my slower PC's, I find using HD makes a noticeable delay in video display, and switching back show motion without delay.

It is unlikely your computer has a "USB port card" that you can replace. Your hardware should generally be sufficient for most modern application. I have an older computer than this with lower hardware specs that does not stutter with USB audio or video. While you have shown that two USB devices are having similar problems, that does not mean the problem is the same thing, or that the problem is with the hardware. Generally, start your troubleshooting with simpler things, and software is simpler.

So, check for and install the latest available drivers and firmware, check for software that is running using too many resources and figure out why this is the case, check for any sort of audio or camera processing "enhancements" which you can disable to use fewer resources, complete an OS repair install, etc. These and other steps should all be done before you dive into hardware replacement.
